# Open page from IFrame from Form

Tags: forms, iframe, parent

I'd like to go to the URL from the form which is in an IFrame.

```
    <form><input name="Button" Type="button" class="btnsmall" onClick="window.location.href='1200X900S.html' target="_parent" value="View details"></form>
```

It's loading the url into the Iframe and not the main page. 
I know this is really simple but with my limited knowledge I'm struggling!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Then why are you using iframe ? you can simply put that button somewhere else .

Comment: I have a form which makes a selection and brings the results up in a certain Iframe, different selections brings up other iframes. I need the user to select the sizes of the rpducts and for them then to click this form button to open into the specific product page.. it's complicated! 

I have normal links from the iframes which work well with 'parent' but this form is't working and I'm not sure why.